# Get ms access connection throw SQLDataException: data exception: numeric value out of range

Tags: sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

get connection throw SQLDataException: data exception: numeric value out of range when table contains a column that type is **single precision**, and it's **value is 3.402823E+38 or -3.402823E+38**.

I use UCanAccess-4.0.4, thanks everyone.

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFJDF.png)

[Program and exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiLFQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. It has been forwarded to the UCanAccess development team.